# AWS Lambda python ldap query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ldap, python-ldap, ldap3

try to find user information from ldap, but I get the `timed out` error. locally it is working

I've tried with both `python-ldap` and `ldap3`

at this moment, I am confused as I see some documentation and instruction how to use/deploy ldap on AWS Lambda but also found from [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/foundation-networking.html) *Lambda supports two types of connections: TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) and UDP (User Datagram Protocol).*

so at the end, is it possible to connect to ldap?

```
import ldap

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    baseDN = 'xxx'
    searchDN = 'xxx'
    pw = "xxx"

    ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
    ldap_host = 'ldaps://ldap-server:3377'
    ldap_conn = ldap.initialize(ldap_host)

    ldap_conn.simple_bind_s(baseDN, pw)

    user = 'testuser'

    result = ldap_conn.search_s(searchDN,
                              ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                              f'(sAMAccountName={user})',['userAccountControl'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Explain it to someone, in this case here, then it will pop up some possible fix into your head

so the issue was I had to attach the VPC with correct Security group into Lmbda configuration.

Comment: In short, you needed to [configure the Lambda function to access resources in your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html), by the sound of things.